# Unable to find Lucene contrib jar in maven repository

Tags: jar, lucene

This is probably a very basic question, but I am unable to find `Lucene` contrib jar in Apache's `Maven` repository. For e.g. I looked [here](http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/lucene/lucene-contrib/3.0.3/), but there's only a `.pom`, there's no jar file, same with repositories mentioned [here](https://repository.apache.org/index.html#view-repositories;snapshots-group~browsestorage).

Am I missing anything obvious?

Answer (score 1):

You can download the jars for maven repositories in here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.lucene/lucene-core/4.4.0

For the contrib package there is a .jar only for the 3.0.2 and not 3.0.3 (don't know why):
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.lucene/lucene-contrib

Also, you can still download de source code and generate the .jar yourself. Should be as easy as running `mvn package`.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer. Except for couple of versions mentioned by [Felipe Hummel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/40876/felipe-hummel), there is not single contrib jar. Contrib contains multiple components such as analyzers, highlighters, etc. and each of them have a JAR.